# Javascript quick start tutorial

Tags: javascript

I've been running through the leaflet [quick start](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) guide but without much success.

My code is as follows:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>

<!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="mapid"></div>

mapid { height: 180px; }

var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);


 L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y} 
   ?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a 
href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> 
contributors, Imagery © <a 
href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken:'XXXX'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

It seems to be going a bit awry at the #mapid command. Does anybody have any suggestions, please?

Comment: Can you clarify what specifically "It seems to be going a bit awry" means in this case?  How exactly is the code failing?  If what you're showing is indeed your exact code then the main problem is that you are mixing HTML, CSS, and JavaScript all together.

Comment: Did you use the request token for Mapbox?

Comment: Yes, I have the access token but I deleted it as I didn’t think I should disclose it

Answer (score 0):

The quick start guide example says "In this example we’ll use the mapbox/streets-v11 tiles from Mapbox’s Static Tiles API (in order to use tiles from Mapbox, you must also request an access token)".

It won't work without it.

[Here is a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fender90/ah07n6ou) for Leaflet with OpenStreetMap Tiles, I think this is what you are looking for.

And also your CSS is missing an #! Should be `#mapid { // }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’m familiar with r/Python but need to put some images on a map so I thought leaflet would be suitable but I need to use JavaScript. When I opened the code in a browser, it just displays the code with no map. Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean you can't see the map in the JSFiddle?

Comment: I’m trying the fiddle now! Thanks :)